Evaluating $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\cos((x+y)^2)\;dydx$

Evaluate:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\cos((x+y)^2)\;dydx$$

This is a problem from a book that I'm reading. The provided solution used the change of the variables $u=x+y$ and $v=y$. I think it is easy to see that we should use $u=x+y$, but I'm not sure how to recognize $v=y$. I have solved several problems using $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, but I'm wondering how to recognize $v=y$ for this integral.
Edit:
The region of integration is enclosed by three lines: $y=0$, $y=1-x$, and $x=0$.
Using $u=x+y$ we have $u=1$. Now for the variable $v$:

If we use $v=y$: $y=0$ implies $v=0$ and $x=0$ implies $u=v$.

If we use $v=x$: $x=0$ implies $v=0$ and $y=0$ implies $u=v$.


So I think we can use either $v=x$ or $v=y$.
Here is my answer for $u=x+y$ and $v=x$:
$$J'=\begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}& \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\  \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\  1 & 0 \end{vmatrix}=-1\quad\Rightarrow\quad J=1
$$
$$\int_0^1\int_0^u\cos u^2 \;dvdu=\int_0^1 u\cos u^2du=1/2\sin u^2\vert_0^1=\dfrac{\sin 1}2$$

$v=(0)(x)+(1)(y)$. Why is this different from the other changes of variables you have seen?

@geetha290krm I don't know how to recognize this at the first place.

Think about your region of integration, and what changes of variables would make any of the boundaries constants.

@NinadMunshi Thanks I think I'm progressing, I will edit my post.

Fantastic edit! Now you get it

Another solution can exploit the polar coordinates as
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\cos((x+y)^2)\;dydx
{
=
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{1}{\cos \phi+\sin\phi}\cos(r^2(\cos \phi+\sin\phi)^2)rdrd\phi
\\=
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(r^2(\cos \phi+\sin\phi)^2)}{2(\cos \phi+\sin\phi)^2}|_0^\frac{1}{\cos \phi+\sin\phi}d\phi
\\=
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(1)}{2(\cos \phi+\sin\phi)^2}d\phi
\\=
\frac{\sin(1)}{4}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{\cos^2 (\phi-\pi/4)}d\phi
\\=
\frac{\sin(1)}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{\cos^2 \phi}d\phi
\\=
\frac{\sin(1)}{2}\tan\phi|_0^\frac{\pi}{4}
\\=
\frac{\sin(1)}{2}.
}
$$
